# Finding the 'absolute mean' of an amplitude - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mean

I need to retrieve the absolute mean value from a sine wave. I've been instructed to do it like this:

You'll need a variable to store the sum of the samples in the array, which you should initialize to zero. Then go through each sample in the array, getting the absolute value and add it to the sum.

Finally, you need to divide the final sum by the number samples in the array. That gets you your mean.

Instead of doing the absolute you could square the values. Then you'd get the root mean square!

As a result, I have come up with this code:

```
float sum = 0;

for (i = 0; samples.length; i ++)
{
    float abs = fabsf(float samples[i]);
    sum += abs;
}

mean = sum / samples.length;
```

However, I am getting errors in the first and second lines... Can anyone help me here? I also need a function to give back the values using NSLog maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you have exactly? `float abs = fabsf(samples[i]);`? What is `samples` (how is it defined)? If it's a NS(Mutable)Array, then `float abs = fabsf([samples[i] floatValue]);`

Comment: samples is an array that stores the number of samples in the sine wave.

Comment: the first error is: Expected ';'at the end of declaration list and the second is the same and also type name requires a specifier or qualifier

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
  for (i = 0; samples.length; i ++)
```

The second clause should be a boolean expression which is true if the loop should keep going.  You also need to declare `i`.

I think you mean

```
 for (NSInteger i = 0; i < samples.length; i ++)
```

Also:

```
 fabsf(float samples[i])
```

should probably be:

```
 fabsf((float)(samples[i]))
```

You might have other errors, but you should tell us the compiler error you are getting if you want more help.  For example: is `mean` declared?

Comment: I was about to write the same thing

Comment: mean is declared as: 
float mean;
mean = sum / samples.length;